# Use a compound "and" in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

Upon trying to emulate the following expression in ES

`expr1 && expr2 && expr3`

And I came up with this

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/policy_router-2019.12.30/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must" : [
        {
                "range" : { "@timestamp": { "gte": "now-15s", "lte": "now"} }
          },
        {
           "query_string": { "query": "rewriteGateway", "default_field" : "message" }
         },
         {
            "query_string": {"query": "policy-router-summer-snow-5555" ,"default_field" : "host" }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}'
```

But, it seems I'm not able to equate what I want, correctly with the above query. i.e  every time I run the above query I see the documents which has host value different what I want it to be i.e `policy-router-summer-snow-5555` here

I also tried nesting `must` inside the outer must but that resulted in a syntax error.

I'm failing to understand why does the last `query_string` expression for the host does not match.

Following is my ES version

```
{
  "name" : "an2FbQZ",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "gIk5QPI3Rb6NPckeCRaUqQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "b2f0c09",
    "build_date" : "2017-08-14T12:33:14.154Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Following is how my document looks like (this is one of the documents returned for the above query, it can be seen clearly that the host does not match)

````
{
        "_index" : "policy_router-2019.12.31",
        "_type" : "policy_router",
        "_id" : "AW9aG7_1tIiuv3oe07ZO",
        "_score" : 4.6003995,
        "_source" : {
          "severity" : "INFO",
          "input" : "udp",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-12-31T03:59:25.107Z",
          "@version" : "1",
          "host" : "policy-router-proud-cherry-2098",
          "message" : "2019-12-31 03:59:25.107111 I [PolicyRouter::Push] PolicyRouter -- PR -> LA ... rewrite gateway ... ",
          "type" : "policy_router"
        }
      }```

Any guidance here from ES expert.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query along with your field's name and value.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "FIELD": {
              "gte": 10,
              "lte": 20
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "FIELD": "PHRASE"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "FIELD": "PHRASE"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```